# Sidebar on right of centered main content

Tags: css, html

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4axkLm9a/

I want the sidebar to appear on the right side of the main content which should stay centered on the page.

I'm trying to design this page so that the main content will be centered on the page, and a sidebar where I can display a vertical banner ad.

Can someone help please? :)

thanks.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="header">

     <div id="main">
          <div id="inner">

          </div>
     </div>  
     <div id="sidebar"></div>    
</div>  

<div id="footer"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0; 
    height:100%;
}


#header{
    background-color:#f0f0f5; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    font-family:Arial, 
    sans-serif; 
    font-size:14px
}

#main {

    padding-bottom:20px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:784px; 
    height:100%;
}

#inner {

    border:1px solid #c9c9c9; 
    padding:20px 20px;  
    color:#44423c; 
    background-color:#fff
}

#sidebar {

    width:200px;
}

#footer {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding-bottom:18px; 
    padding-top:18px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:1030px
    font:normal 14px/1em Arial, sans-serif; 
    color:#727272; 
    text-align:center;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your code. [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4axkLm9a/14/)

```
#sidebar {
  float: right;
}

#inner {
  float: left;
  width: 584px;
}
```

Additionally, you should change your code to use semantic html, such as:

```
<header>
</header>

  <main>
    <article>
    </article> 
    <aside>
    </aside>
  </main>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Also you need to end your #header div before you start the #main div.

Header

```
<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="main">
  <div id="inner">
    Inner Content
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    Sidebar Content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright Website Blah Blah </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **position: fixed**

On your **#sidebar** id add:

```
 position: fixed;
 right: 0px;
 top: 50%;
```

[Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/loruit/7puuurdd/)